# Cancel edit in QTableView when delegate loses focus

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a basic QTableView + QAbstractTableModel architecture.
Data can be edited via a QAbstractItemDelegate subclass. Everything works as expected but I need to slightly change the editing behaviour:

Qt default behaviour is:

- For an open delegate editor, hitting Enter confirms the edit
- For an open delegate editor, hitting Escape cancels the edit
- For an open delegate editor, clicking in a different table view cell confirms the edit

I want to get rid of the last one. If the delegate editor loses focus, the edit shall be canceled (i. e. it shall not emit editingFinished()) so that a user can only submit changes by pressing Enter.

Is there a convenient way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in my application, and here's my solution:

Digging into QAbstractItemDelegate's source code (by finding `commitData`), you could find a private function `editorEventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)`, which has the following code (simplified):

```cpp
if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
    // just handling Esc/Enter/Return key strokes...
} else if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut || (event->type() == QEvent::Hide && editor->isWindow())) {
    // ok it's now handling focus related events

    if (!editor->isActiveWindow() || (QApplication::focusWidget() != editor)) {
        QWidget *w = QApplication::focusWidget();
        // lines omitted: checking focus is in editor or editor's child

        if (tryFixup(editor))
            emit q->commitData(editor);  // <- here
    }
} // else if (...) {...}
```

and here's the `tryFixup` function:

```cpp
bool QAbstractItemDelegatePrivate::tryFixup(QWidget *editor)
{
    if (QLineEdit *e = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor)) {
        if (!e->hasAcceptableInput()) {
            // fix input using validator.fixup()
            // if QLineEdit has a QValidator
            return e->hasAcceptableInput();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

So, for most cases, QAbstractItemDelegate would commit an editor's data when the editor loses its focus. To prevent this behaviour, we can override `eventFilter` and filter out the `QFocusOutEvent` and `QHideEvent`. I'm using PySide6 6.5.0, and here's the code:

```py
def checkObjectIsEditor(self, obj):
    return False  # maybe something like isinstance(obj, YourEditorType)

def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if (
        self.checkObjectIsEditor(object)
        and event.type() in [QEvent.Type.FocusOut, QEvent.Type.Hide]
    ):
        widget = QApplication.focusWidget()
        while widget:
            if self.checkIsEditor(widget):
                return False
            widget = widget.parentWidget()
        # The focus is neither in editor nor in its child.
        # Now close the editor, and not commiting its data.

        object.hide()
        object.deleteLater()
        # or maybe self.destroyEditor(object)
        return True  # stop the event from propagating
    return super().eventFilter(object, event)
```

Hope this helps anyone in need.

Answer (score 0):

Override the class, find out which function that last behaviour is that you dont want, then override that function and just leave the implementation of it empty, then it gets called just as it would usually but now it does nothing (or does something else, you're programming it make it do whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

Set a property on the editor widget only when the user interacts with it, and check that this property is correctly set inside `setModelData()` before modifying your model.

For instance, we have a ButtonDelegate that seemed to get triggered when focusing out. We applied a property to know when `setModelData()` was triggered by a click like so:

```cpp
QWidget * ButtonDelegate::createEditor(QWidget * parent,
                                       QStyleOptionViewItem const &,
                                       QModelIndex const &) const
{
    auto editor = new QToolButton(parent);
    connect(editor, &QAbstractButton::clicked, this, [=]
    {
        editor->setProperty("clicked", true);
        Q_EMIT const_cast<ButtonDelegate *>(this)->commitData(editor);
    });
    return editor;
}

void ButtonDelegate::setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model,
                                  QModelIndex const & index) const
{
    if (model && index.isValid() && editor->property("clicked") == true)
    {
        model->setData(index, true, Qt::CheckStateRole);
        editor->setProperty("clicked", {}); // Reset to handle next click
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would override the `QAbstractItemModel::setData()` in your model and skip emitting `dataChanged()` on attempt to set the same data as it is already existing for the given item.